# A Gradle task (type: Exec) is not executed during the configuration phase

Tags: gradle

I am reading about [Gradle build lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html)

Here is my script:

```
task startTomcat(type:Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'echo init startTomcat'
} 

task stopTomcat(type:Exec) {

    // on windows:
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'echo init stopTomcat!'
    doLast {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'echo doLast stopTomcat!'
    }
}


task configured(type:Exec) {
    println 'configured. method body'
}

task test2 {
    doLast {
        println 'test2 doLast'
    }
}

task testBoth2 {
    doFirst {
      println 'testBoth2 doFirst'
    }
    doLast {
      println 'testBoth2 doLast'
    }
    println 'testBoth2. method body'
}
```

I run task2:

```
gradlew test2
```

This is the output:

```
Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
configured. method body
testBoth2. method body
:test2
test2 doLast

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

It looks like the calls to `commandLine` were ignored. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Exec` [task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html)'s `commandLine` properly only configures what to do *if* the task is executed. As such you don't see the actual command doing anything during the configuration phase.